# How to autotile similar type of tiles in order?

Tags: godot

(Godot -v3.5)

Let's say I'm adding the following floor tilemap and I want to autotile them:
[image]

How do I set the bitmask such that when placed the pattern is always `1234`?

examples:

```
12  
1234  
1234123, etc
```

Comment: This is tricky and I have been experimenting to try and find out. Ill answer if I find anything. But I do have an idea. Maybe you can do this in code. Every 1st tile is 1, and so on.

Comment: @TheJalfireKnight I thought of using tool mode but that opens a whole new plethora of problems, do answer if you have a direct approach